# SSH asking some passwords in the terminal and others in the GUI (gnome-keyring)

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring, ssh-agent

After having the Ubuntu updated from 20.04 to 22.04, ssh started asking some passwords in the GUI (and they are kept as expected), but others are asked in the terminal and they aren't kept.

If I add the keys through `ssh-add` it stops asking me the key password and ssh works silently as expected, with both the passwords I added into the `ssh-agent` manually and the passwords previously asked and kept by the GUI (`gnome-keyring`).

How to fix that and force it to use only the GUI?

Comment: @user68186: sorry for any misunderstanding, the question is about ssh keys (`ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`), so password/passphrase to unlock keys. It looks like that password and passphrase seem kind of interchangeable here. Although ssh calls it a "passphrase", the `gnome-keyring` GUI asks you for the key password and not a passphrase, precisely "Enter password to unlock the private key",

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! Some of my `.pub` key files were gone!

I just restored them and everything worked like a charm. However, the incident was a result of a customization and so it was not a Ubuntu 22.04 installation issue.

More about a similar issue when `.pub` files are missing. It looks like `gnome-keyring` needs the public key file (.pub) alongside to the private key file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269134/926064